# How to add MousePressed Eventhandler to addItem new JButton

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton

```
addItem = new JButton("Add");
gc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
gc.weightx = 1.0;
panel.add(addItem, gc);
```

Am I able to make it into something like that:

```
addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
```

Instead of this I would want that button, but I have no idea what does that addItem do, since it does not let me to add a name there.

Is there a way how I can do this without modifying the 4 rows of code given at the beginning of the question?

Comment: You never want to use a MouseListener for listening to JButtons but rather ActionListeners. You will want to read the tutorials on this stuff as they're quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Code using an inner class instead of EventHandler.

```
  addItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

you can get more information on this in java official website. 
Refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html

if you add just the mouse listener you will not get the 'press' event if using keyboard. So, if your requirement is strictly bound to mouse press then use below snippet :)

```
addItem.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // do something

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // do something

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // do something

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // do something

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // do something

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to add ActionListener to the button click or if you want you can add MouseListener , actually it depends on what you want to do

```
addItem.addActionListener(new ActtionListener() {...});
```